# convert Array to indicator matrix

Tags: arrays, julia

Given the y Array, is there a cleaner or more idiomatic way to create a 2D Array such as Y?

```
y = [1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0 1.0 2.0]'

Y = ifelse(y .== 1, 1.0, 0.0)
for j in 2:length(unique(y))
   Y = hcat(Y, ifelse(y .== j, 1.0, 0.0) )
end

julia> Y
6x4 Array{Float64,2}:
 1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
 0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0
 0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0
 0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0
 1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
 0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0
```

Comment: Just a note on terminology: `y` is not a 1D Array; it is a 2D, 6x1 Array as evidenced by `ndims(y)`. See http://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/noteworthy-differences/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One alternative approach is to use [`broadcast`](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.4/manual/arrays/#broadcasting):

```
julia> broadcast(.==, y, (1:4)')
6x4 Array{Float64,2}:
 1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
 0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0
 0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0
 0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0
 1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
 0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0
```

(`.==` broadcasts automatically, so if you just wanted a BitArray you could write `y .== (1:4)'`.)

This avoids the explicit `for` loop and also the use of `hcat` to build the array. However, depending on the size of the array you're looking to create, it might be most efficient to allocate an array of zeros of the appropriate shape and then use indexing to add the ones to the appropriate column on each row.

Answer (score 2):

Array comprehension is an idiomatic and fast way to create matrices in Julia. For the example in the question:

```
y = convert(Vector{Int64},vec(y)) # make sure indices are integer
Y = [j==y[i] ? 1.0 : 0.0 for i=1:length(y),j=1:length(unique(y))]
```

What was probably intended was:

```
Y = [j==y[i] ? 1.0 : 0.0 for i=1:length(y),j=1:maximum(y)]
```

In both cases Y is:

```
6x4 Array{Float64,2}:
 1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
 0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0
 0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0
 0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0
 1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
 0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0
```

Answer (score 1):

> In numerical analysis, a **sparse matrix** is a matrix in which most of
>   the elements are zero.

And from Julia Doc:
`sparse(I,J,V,[m,n,combine])`

> Create a sparse matrix S of dimensions m x n such that S[I[k], J[k]] =
>   V[k]. The combine function is used to combine duplicates. If m and n
>   are not specified, they are set to max(I) and max(J) respectively. If
>   the combine function is not supplied, duplicates are added by default.

```
y = [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2] 
rows=length(y);
clms=4 # must be >= maximum(y);
s=sparse(1:rows,y,ones(rows),rows,clms);
full(s) # => 
6x4 Array{Float64,2}:
 1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
 0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0
 0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0
 0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0
 1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
 0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0
```